# Saving data into plist with iOS

Tags: ios, plist

I am trying to add data to plist but I could not, let's tell you what I am doing:

Have a look to my plist:

[image]

Lets see my code, I created 2 arrays:

```
@property NSMutableArray *nameArr;
@property NSMutableArray *countryArr;
```

Here is the code where I save the data:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];

[self.nameArr addObject:self.theName.text];
[self.countryArr addObject:self.cellPhone.text];

NSDictionary *plistDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: self.nameArr, self.countryArr, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"city", @"state", nil]];

NSString *error = nil;
NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:plistDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];

if(plistData)
{
    [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"Data Saved");

}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Data not saved");

}
```

The below image shows the error, the app terminate but I do not know where is the problem.

[image]

Comment: your plist data setup looks all wrong. plist should contain one dictionary with multiple arrays and each of those arrays should have a corresponding one key value each.

Comment: Did you copy and paste this code from somewhere or do you know what's happening?

Comment: I did copy and change some, I am not good with plist. In the same time I can retrieve data from the same plist in a tableview

Comment: I need a help Sam B

Comment: google it buddy - https://www.google.com/search?q=save+plist+objective+c&rlz=1C1CHBD_enUS707US707&oq=save+plist+objective+c&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.8607j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=tutorials+for+saving+plist

Answer (score 1):

Probably the array properties are declared but never initialized.

You have to add

```
nameArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
countryArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

somewhere before using them.

Regarding the warning use the method suggested by the compiler.